# Why am I getting 'object is not a function' on this form?

Tags: javascript, html

When I submit [this form](http://jsbin.com/ozeyag/9), I'm quickly getting an "object is not a function" error (in Chrome), while the form submits. What's my bug?

I'm sure it's something silly, but for the life of me I don't understand what's wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are correct, but you can avoid all this hassle by using jQuery more properly.

Instead of inline JavaScript inside the form tag, add ID to the form then have such code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myform").bind("submit", validate);
});
```

The form now should look like this:

```
<form id="myform">
```

And don't forget to add the `return false;` to the function itself to prevent submission.

When inside the function, JS will treat `validate` properly as a function - when inline inside the form tag, it looked first in the form elements and found the button - hence the error you got.

Comment: nice answer - I would definitely use jQuery binding over inline functions.

Answer (score 4):

I just changed your function name `validate()` to `formVal()`, and now it's working just fine - it's because you have an element with id of validate.

Change the function name to `formVal()` (or anything apart from `validate()`), then change the form tag to say this:

```
<form onSubmit='return formVal();'>
```

It now comes up saying "Valid!" in a heading tag below the form. There is also no error.

Answer (score 3):

You have function 'validate' and submit button has got id 'validate'. Change one of them.

Comment: Or he could take out the jquery #'s